# SQL Query to select from a table using a WHERE clause on another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to run this SQL Query in PHP:

```
$sql="select b.company as c, c.company, c.resellerid from billing b, customer c WHERE (b.company = c.customerid OR b.company = c.voip_account OR b.company = c.sequence) AND c.resellerid = '0' and source = 'CDR' group by b.company asc ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $sql2="select company,extension,phone,calltype,seconds,who,customer_bill,inclusive,timestamp from billing where company='".$result["c"]."' and source='CDR' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);

    echo $result["c"].' - '.$result2["company"].'<br>';
}
```

`billing.company` can equal any of the following

```
customer.sequence
customer.customerid
customer.voip_account
```

i want to select all the rows in the `billing` table where `customer.resellerid = 0` and:

```
billing.company = customer.sequence OR billing.company = customer.customerid OR billing.company = customer.voip_account
```

but its returning rows where `resellerid` is not equal to 0

Comment: khm...what? `b.company as c, c.company, c.resellerid `, btw to use more than one table in one query you will need inner or left join

Comment: The logic of your database structure escapes me.

Comment: the database was designed by someone else, i just need this query to work

Comment: The problem is that in your second query you select *all* CDR billings of the companies just found with the first query, and you don't ask for records with resellerid = 0 anymore. Add this criteria to your second query and it will work. However, as Strawberry pointed out: why have two queries at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why there are two queries...

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.company b_company
              , b.extension
              , b.phone
              , b.calltype
              , b.seconds
              , b.who
              , b.customer_bill
              , b.inclusive,timestamp
              , c.company c_company
              , c.resellerid 
           FROM billing b
           JOIN customer c 
             ON b.company IN(c.company,c.voip_account,c.sequence) 
            AND c.resellerid = 0 
            AND source = 'CDR' 
          ORDER 
             BY b.company;
```

And please note that PHP's mysql_ API is long since deprecated